# Exception in thread "main" java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect while running flutter app in emulator

Tags: flutter, dart

I am getting this error while running this app in emulator. On web, its working fine but not on emulator.

```
Launching lib\main.dart on sdk gphone64 x86 64 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
Exception in thread "main" java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    `at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.BaseSSLSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.New(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Download.downloadInternal(Download.java:58)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Download.download(Download.java:44)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:61)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:48)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAccessManager.java:65)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.createDist(Install.java:48)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:128)
    `at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:61)`
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1`
```

Please help.

I tried searching on net but couldn't find anything.

Comment: I'm also getting this problem on a new flutter project